# How to implement Kafka in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka

What would be the best way to implement Kafka in a Django application. Should I use `kafka-python` or `django-lopipe`. Could you please suggest any demo or sample reference document to start with.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `django-logpipe` is built on top of `kafka-python`. Have a look at their READMEs on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Confluent Kafka Python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) in your application. [Here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/tree/master/examples) you can find various examples for usage of Kafka clients .